# Make flex item have same width as parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a slider using flex boxes. The idea i have is to create a parent container and have the sliders overflowing horizontally. The parent would then be set to have overflow none so that the overflowing children are hidden and we are able to use the scroll bar to view other child elements.

```css
.slider-container {
  width: inherit;
  height: 40em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: inherit;
}

.slide {
  height: inherit;
}

.x {
  background-color: green;
}

.y {
  background-color: red;
}

.z {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="x">XXXXX</div>
    <div class="y">YYYYY</div>
    <div class="z">ZZZZZ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The below image shows the output i am getting now. I am trying to make the three divs to have the full width of the parent container. This way only the red div should be visible while it occupies the space of the parent div. To view the rest of the divs we must scroll right.

I have tried setting the width to 100% but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Current View]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `flex: 0 0 100%` (don't grow, don't shrink, base width is 100% of parent) on the divs:

```css
.slider-container {
  width: inherit;
  height: 40em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.x {
  background-color: green;
}

.y {
  background-color: red;
}

.z {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item x">XXXXX</div>
    <div class="item y">YYYYY</div>
    <div class="item z">ZZZZZ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi when i make the .slider have translateX(50px) why is the whole flex box shrinking instead of giving a scroll effect ?

Comment: The scroll effect works fine if the flex: 0 0 100% is removed but in such a situation it gets small again.

Comment: Use `transform: translateX(-100px);` and remove ` overflow-x: scroll;
`. I've updated the example.

Comment: Thanks alot its exactly what ive been looking for. If you could, can you explain why the whole .slider div shifts to the right when overflow-x: scroll is present ?  and works the way I except when it is removed.

Comment: Sorry I can't :). Some idiosyncrasy in the interaction between the two.

Comment: @Muljayan it's due to the default margin in the body (8px). When adding overflow:scroll you see a small part of the second div in the right 8px of margin